# How do I retrieve the endpoint of an Azure Notification Hub Access policy using powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-notificationhub

I have a need to programmatically, using Powershell, retrieve the endpoint of a NotificationHub Access Policy.

I have tried **Get-AzNotificationHubsListKey** from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.notificationhubs/get-aznotificationhubauthorizationrule?view=azps-5.4.0:

```
$ruleKey = Get-AzNotificationHubsListKey `
  -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName `
  -Namespace $notificationsHubNamespace `
  -NotificationHub $notificationHub `
  -AuthorizationRule $ruleName
```

But this throws the error:

```
Get-AzNotificationHubsListKey: The term 'Get-AzNotificationHubsListKey' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
```

Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo in your command. Based on [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.notificationhubs/get-aznotificationhublistkey?view=azps-5.4.0), it should be `Get-AzNotificationHubListKey`, while you have `Get-AzNotificationHubSListKey`.

Comment: Thanks. Spent ages looking at that and not seeing it.